# R - generate dataframe so that each value appears the same number of times

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe of size 1000 in R which would be composed of 10 variables which can all take integer values from 1 to 10.

This is a fairly simple thing to do, for example like this:

```
library(foreach)

foreach (i = 1:1000, .combine = "rbind") %do% {
  sample(1:10, 10)
}
```

However, what I need is to ensure that each value appears in each column exactly 100 times.

For example, the value "1" must appear 100 times in the first column, 100 times in the second column, 100 times in the third column, and so forth until the tenth column, in which it should also appear 100 times.

Likewise, the value "2" should appear 100 times in the first column, 100 times in the second column and so on, and this continues with all values.

There are many possible combinations of how this could look like and I just want to randomly draw one of these combinations. How could I do that?

Comment: how about creating the dataset with the desired specifications and just shuffling the rows randomly ?

Comment: @MatiasAndina, Sorry, I don't follow. This is what my question is about -  how to create a dataset with such specifications. My question is not about the order of rows within such dataset.

Comment: You mean you want to do something like `tibble::tibble(x = rep(1:10, each = 100))` (you can also use `data.frame` or `matrix`) here if you want and then replicate this as columns (see some of the answers that use the same approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `replicate` with `sample`:

```
reps <- rep(1:10, each = 100)
data <- replicate(10, sample(reps, 1000))

# if you want it in a data frame structure:
df <- data.frame(data)
```

Output

```
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#   [1,]    6    1    2    9    3    2    4    5    6     5
#   [2,]    4    7    6    1    9    5    1    8    5     1
#   [3,]    9    9    6   10    2    8    8    7   10     7
#   [4,]    4    2    6    7    1    5    8    5    5     8
#   [5,]    4    4    4    6    3    1    9    8    3    10
# ....
```

Check:

```
apply(data, 2, table)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
2   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
3   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
4   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
5   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
6   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
7   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
8   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
9   100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
10  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents here:

```
library(dplyr)
# generate specified data frame
df <- data.frame(sapply(paste0('col', 1:10), function(x) rep(1:10, each = 100)))
# shuffle columns independently
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sample(., 1000)))
```

We can check here that the numbers are there:

```
> table(df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sample(., 1000))) %>% pull(col1))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
> table(df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sample(., 1000))) %>% pull(col2))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
> table(df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sample(., 1000))) %>% pull(col3))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `data.frame` containing the not shuffled values using `matrix` and `as.data.frame` and then use `sample` on the columns.

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, 1000, 10))

DF[] <- lapply(DF, sample)
#for(i in seq_along(DF)) DF[[i]] <- sample(DF[[i]]) #Alternative

sapply(DF, table)
#    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10
#1  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#2  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#3  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#4  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#5  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#6  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#7  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#8  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#9  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
#10 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```